# How to create global protocol method in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios6, protocols, global

I create one protocol method and I want to implement the protocol method in multiple classes

```
@protocol XMLProtocol <NSObject>

- (BOOL) hasAllRequiredAttributes :(NSDictionary*)attributeMap;

@end
```

I have use this following class methods

```
#import "XMLProtocol.h"
@interface MachineA : NSObject<XMLProtocol>
```

and its implementation method I will implement the protocol method

```
- (BOOL) hasAllRequiredAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeMap {
  return false;
  }
```

and also i use this protocol method in another class

```
#import "XMLProtocol.h"
@interface MachineB : NSObject<XMLProtocol>
```

and its implementation method I will implement the protocol method

```
- (BOOL) hasAllRequiredAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeMap {
  return false;
 }
```

my thought is where should I call the protocol method. I totally confused. How can i do this.

Comment: what do you mean by: "where should I call the protocol method"?

Comment: @sergio where should i initiate the protocol method. its means define the protocol method what should its do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you can define a global implementation for your protocol method (if I understand correctly what you are asking) is defining a category on NSObject:

```
@implementation NSObject (XMLProtocol)

- (BOOL) hasAllRequiredAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeMap {
   return false;
}
```

By doing like this **every** object will have that method. Don't know if this is sensible, but it's a way.

Another way would be defining a `Machine` base class from which both `MachineA` and `MachineB` derive; the protocol method would be defined in the base class:

```
@interface Machine : NSObject <XMLProtocol>
   ...
@implementation Machine
- (BOOL) hasAllRequiredAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeMap {
   return false;
}
    ....
@end

@interface MachineA : Machine
 ...
```

and any derived class could redefine it, if required.

This is not as "global" as the NSObject category, but it might be a better solution if you can define a base class for all the classes that need implement that protocol.

Answer (score 0):

You must write the implementation of the method in both classes, even if the implementations are identical.

Answer (score 0):

In you particular situation notification would be great help full to you. Notification works same like protocol except it broadcast the message. so you could receive that call on multiple classes.

if you want to done with protocol than also it is very easy. just make sure you current view controller is referenced with delegate (i.e. obj.delegate = self). you can implement that on -viewWillAppear. so your current view controller only get called of that method. Delegate will only call one method at one place in a time.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO a global protocol is not very good design for something as specific as XML parsing.

A `@protocol` doesn't have any implementation part by itself. It is just an API definition, think of it like a contract. Any class that conforms to a protocol must implement its mandatory methods and properties (there is a `@optional` clause).

For instance, you may have two implementations of an XML parser, one that works in iOS 4 and another one that works in iOS 5+. Both declared as conforming to `XMLProtocol` protocol. And *both implementing* `- (BOOL) hasAllRequiredAttributes :(NSDictionary*)attributeMap;`, let's imagine that they need to implement it differently.

Thanks to being compliant to `XMLProtocol` you don't care about the implementation details. You know that you'll pass an attribute map and you'll obtain a boolean indicating if it has all required attributes.

You call the method where ever you use those classes:

```
id <XMLProcotol> parser;
if (iOS4) {
    parser = [[OldXMLParser alloc] initWithString:<#...#>];
} else {
    parser = [[NewXMLParser alloc] initWithString:<#...#>];
}
/* you call the method without caring which parser class
 * has been actually created thanks to the protocol
 */
if ([parser hasAllRequiredAttributes:theMap]) {
    ...
}
```

If the implementation of the methods are identical, you can make both a subclass of a common parent class that implements the common methods, present or not in the protocol.